# Android Parsing XML

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-sqlite

I need Relational Data in my app whose data will be loaded from two XML Files which will be either stored in `assets` folder or downloaded from the `Server`.

```
categories(id, name, slug) // using a slug string to select the category icon drawable in list view
places(id, name, ...., category_id)
images(id, path, place_id)
```

Now based on this have built the following XML

categories.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<categories>
    <category>
        <name>Hill Station</name>
        <icon>hill-station</icon>
    </category>

    <category>
        <name>Water Fall</name>
        <icon>water-fall</icon>
    </category>
.
.
.
.

</categories>
```

places.xml

```
<places>
    <place>
        <name>Nandi hills</name>
        <category>hill-station</category>
        <distance>70</distance>
        <days>1</days>
        <latitude>13.3333</latitude>
        <longitude>77.6500</longitude>
        <weather>Summer 25°-28°C, Winter 8°-10°C</weather>
        <todo>Para-Gliding, Tippu Drop, Gardens, Jumping Jacks</todo>
        <about>Nandi Hills or Nandidurg is an ancient hill fortress of southern India, 
            in the Chikkaballapur district of Karnataka state. It is located just 10 km from 
            Chickballapur town and approximately 60 km from the city of Bangalore. The hills are 
            nestled between the neighboring towns of Nandi, Muddenahalli, and Kanivenarayanapura.
            The hills are traditionally held as the origin of the Arkavathy river.
        </about>
        <images>
            <image>http://i.imgur.com/Y2MMa.jpg</image>
            <image>http://i.imgur.com/DoRXC.jpg</image>
            <image>http://i.imgur.com/ZA8PR.jpg</image>
            <image>http://i.imgur.com/aSeYa.jpg</image>
        </images>
    </place>

    <place>
        <name>Kemmannugundi</name>
        <category>hill-station</category>
        <distance>260</distance>
        <days>2</days>
        <latitude>13.5470</latitude>
        <longitude>75.7580</longitude>
        <weather>Summer 17°-34°C, Winter 12°-29°C</weather>
        <todo>Rajendra hill, Rock garden, Z point, Shiva temple</todo>
        <about>Kemmannugundi is a hill station in Tarikere taluk of Chikkamagaluru district in the state of Karnataka, India. 
            It is 1434m above sea level. This was the summer retreat of Krishnaraja Wodeyar IV and as a mark of respect to the king, 
            it is also known as Sri Krishnarajendra Hill Station. The station is ringed by the Baba Budan Giri Range, with cascades, 
            mountain streams, and lush vegetation, Kemmangundi’s has ornamental gardens and mountains and valleys views. 
            There is a spectacular sunset view from the Raj Bhavan.</about>
        <images>
            <image>http://i.imgur.com/Y2MMa.jpg</image>
            <image>http://i.imgur.com/DoRXC.jpg</image>
            <image>http://i.imgur.com/ZA8PR.jpg</image>
            <image>http://i.imgur.com/aSeYa.jpg</image>
        </images>
    </place>
</places>
```

I am using OrderXMLHandler to parse data right now. Is there any lib that can parse the xml and give objects automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Castor.  I used it many years ago.  It seems to still be an active project.  It provides XML/Object marsahlling/unmarshalling: http://castor.codehaus.org/index.html

JAXB provides the same functionality, but I have heard (i.e. not confirmed) that there are problems running JAXB on Android.